# How to use friend declaration for template class with constraints

Tags: c++, friend, c++20, c++-concepts

For C++20 concepts are intended and some compilers are providing already some early implementations for it. We ran into some problem with friend declarations of template class where the parameters have constraints. After some soul searching and tryng to find anything in the draft standard and associated documents we are not wiser about what is possible and/or correct.

We have tried the standard ideas one would come up to find a solution but didn't arrive at any that would work for all compilers tried or a formal answer from the standard, which might be just bad luck with reading the proper search results.

What we try to attempt is to create a friend relation between a template class and itself making all other instantiations of the template a friend.

The original version looks like

```
template <typename T> concept Constraint = true;

template <Constraint T>
class A { };

struct B {
    template <typename>
    friend class A;
};
```

This compiles in gcc but neither in clang nor the latest MSVC preview compiler

The next attempt is to use the constraints in the friend declaration i.e.

```
template <typename T> concept Constraint = true;

template <Constraint T>
class A { };

struct B {
    template <Constraint>
    friend class A;
};
```

which looks like a natural way of doing it because the friend can only be instantiated anyways with fulfilling the constraints.

This passes with gcc, clang is not happy about it, MSVC is o.K. with the declaration but fails when one is actually trying to use it. It complains that the constraints are not being fulfilled, which is not correct.

One also comes up with putting some class ids into the friend declaration, i.e.

```
template <typename T> concept Constraint = true;

template <Constraint T>
class A { };

struct B {
    template <Constraint U>
    friend class A;
};
```

This results in the same as the previous attempt. 
So far we have not been able to come up with a syntax (if it is even possible) that actually works.
If one doesn't use constraints and uses SFINAE tricks and uses just "typename" it works as expected.

It would be appreciated if anybody would have an idea how to fix it using the actual C++20 features or a pointer where that situation is actually described. We know that we could just use setters and getters but that is not the point.

Answer (score 2):

I'm pretty sure this is the correct version (i.e. your 2nd or 3rd option):

```
template <typename T> concept Constraint = true;

template <Constraint T>
class A { };

struct B {
    template <Constraint> friend class A;
};
```

This should befriend all specializations of `A`. `typename` there would be incorrect, since that would not match the declaration of `A`. I don't think we have specific wording for this, but that seems like the clear intent.

Both gcc and clang accept this version ([demo](https://godbolt.org/z/cpFpok)), and the version of MSVC on compiler-explorer does not yet implement concepts at all.

Comment: Thank's for the answer, it is also what I expected.I am surprised about the clang statement though, we were not able to make it work for clang. We new about the gcc behaviour. MSVC supports concepts in the latest preview versions, i.e. starting  with MSVC 19.3.0 preview 3 if one uses the option std:c++latest. Not all features are implemented, yet. That's why there is no official std:C++20 option, yet.

Comment: I just looked at your answer and see that it is sligthly different from the question.

Comment: @H.Gutsche How is it different from the question? What is the question then?

Comment: I just looked at your an answer and see that it is different from the question. We are not trying to befriend another class, but we want to befriend our self, i.e. what happens if your B changes to A? The friend happens within declaration of it's friend. The attempt is to declare a friend to an  unspecified instance of the template that one is currently declaring. And now I am totally confused because I realize that the question how it currently stands is not the question I asked. Did you edit it??

Comment: @H.Gutsche Yes, I edited the question so that it consists of real code instead of random dots, to make it a better question. It doesn't matter between `B` friending `A` and `A` friending `A`, the correct syntax doesn't change, and both compilers [still accept it](https://godbolt.org/z/pJ0jb2).

Comment: O.K. I just don't know why you would have seen random dots. When I verified it before I submitted it it looked O.K.

Comment: That doesn't look like disconnected dots to me. It is precisely what I intended to do. There was no attempt to show fully functional code. The triple dots were the commonly used symbols for unspecified continuation of a text. They just symbolize that there can be something where the dots are that are rather irrelevant to the problem.
Thanks anyways.

Comment: @H.Gutsche "There was no attempt to show fully functional code [...] the dots just symbolize that there can be something where the dots are that are rather irrelevent" -- yes, I understand that, but in such cases you should just put nothing and have a legitimate code snippet. The dots not only add nothing of value, but actively detract from the ability to understand the snippet. That's precisely why I edited the question to _be_ functional code, and why I would encourage you to do the same in the future.

Comment: @H.Gutsche It is preferable to have the code in the question compileable. If you decide for whatever reason to have `...` in the code, please wrap them in comments so people don't have to modify all occurrences to make the compiler happy. I personally don't mind the ellipses to denote absent code where it clarifies the intent, but that's probably unnecessary in some syntax question where it's fine if the code is otherwise effect-free.

Comment: @Barry it actually does not work in clang if you try to instantiate the class:

https://godbolt.org/z/HEjbKk